# Server Side Includes with variable (IIS 7)

Tags: html, iis-7

I am trying to build a universal header file that I can include in each .html file on my site. My header contains several dropdown tabs, and one of the tabs is always highlighted (depending on which page the user is on). So I want to do something like a server side include for the header, but I also want to give it a variable so that it knows which tab to highlight, something like this:

```
<div class="topmenu">
<ul>
<someScript>
if (variable=="home") {
   print "<li class='current'>";
} else {
   print "<li>";
}
</someScript>
...
```

My server is IIS 7 and doesn't support PHP, and I don't want to rename all my files to *.asp so that I can use ASP. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the extension I guess you would use Classic ASP. Then something like this should work:

```
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
```

You can put this in each file you want to have a header.
Of couse, you should create that "header.asp" page first ;)

For highligthing the tab of the page you're in, there're several methods.
IMHO, I suggest a clientside script to do that. JS or jQuery of course.

You could check the file name of the URL you are in and give the proper class to the tab so it will be highligthed.

Example ( jQuery needed ):

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if(currentPage == 'default.asp') $('li.homepage a').addClass('current');
```

This simple code retrives the file name and, by it, add a class to the corresponding element in your navigation.

Of course this is a conceptual script, you'd better adapt it to your page.

Comment: This is a very clever idea, but since I'm using this header on more than just the homepage, I'd need an "if" statement for every page on the site. Right?

Comment: @BenCaine: With this method, yes.